# Пожалуйста помогите решить проблему с библиотекой Vosk

Tags: python

пытался сделать голосового ассистента. Для начала изучил как можно превратить текст в речь а потом начал думать как бы сделать так что бы мой голос превращался в текс нашёл библиотеку Vosk установил скачал модуль положил её в папку вместе с кодом пишу её полный путь не помогает пишу просто имя тоже не помогло прошу помогите да понимаю ошибка памоему детская но я даже не предполагаю в чём её суть. Опять же не знаю как показать поэтому напишу тут вот код.

```
import json, pyaudio

import vosk
from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer

model = vosk.Model(r'C:\Users\user\Documents\попытки сделать голосового асистента\small_model.zip')
f = KaldiRecognizer(model, 16000)
r = pyaudio.PyAudio()
c = r.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=16000, input=True, frames_per_duffer=8000)
c.start_c()

def l():
    pass

input('good')
```

последняя функция просто для того что бы понять работает ли код.
весь код я взял с ютюба
вот проблема которая выскакивает:

```
ERROR (VoskAPI:Model():model.cc:122) Folder 'C:\Users\user\Documents\попытки сделать голосового асистента\small_model.zip' does not contain model files. Make sure you specified the model path properly in Model constructor. If you are not sure about relative path, use absolute path specification.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\попытки сделать голосового асистента\тест.py", line 6, in <module>
    model = vosk.Model(r'C:\Users\user\Documents\попытки сделать голосового асистента\small_model.zip')
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\vosk\__init__.py", line 57, in __init__
    raise Exception("Failed to create a model")
Exception: Failed to create a model
```

Comment: Ошибка "Failed to create a model" может означать всё, что угодно. Поищите тут поиском, на подобные вопросы было много ответов.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте распаковать файл small_model.zip и указать путь к распакованной папке в строке:

```
model = vosk.Model(r'ПУТЬ_К_РАСПАКОВАННОЙ_ПАПКЕ')
```

Comment: я и показывал путь к распокованной папке

Comment: Это путь не к папке распакованной а к архиву - r'C:\Users\user\Documents\попытки сделать голосового асистента\small_model.zip'

Answer (score 0):

Вот кусок старого кода

```
import vosk #сама либа
import json #анализ результатов
import queue #получение результатов
import sounddevice as sd

que=queue.Queue(1)
folder='mw/tool/ru' #относительный или абсолютный путь к либе
vosk.SetLogLevel(0)
model = vosk.Model(folder)
samplerate = int(sd.query_devices(None, 'input')['default_samplerate'])
rec = vosk.KaldiRecognizer(model, samplerate)

 
with sd.RawInputStream(samplerate=samplerate, blocksize = 8000, dtype='int16',
    channels=1, callback=lambda *it: que.put(bytes(it[0]))):
    data=[]
    while True:
        data = que.get()
        if rec.AcceptWaveform(data):
            print(rec.FinalResult())
            #{  "text" : ""}
            #тут вызов функции обработки полученой инфы то есть реакция ассистента на сказаную фразу
            #action(rec.FinalResult()['text'])
            break
        else:
            #это нужно только для отладки
            print(rec.PartialResult())
            #{ "partial" : ""}
```

То есть главный цикл воска должен работать постоянно, если у ассистента будет гуи то нужно будет реализовать многопоточность либо взаимодействие скриптов.
Так же у воска есть проблемма- постоянный рост оперативной памяти,- перезапуск воска результата не даёт,- только перезапуск скрипта.

Comment: если я указываю обсалютный путь к мамке с модулем то выскакивает эта ошибка:

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

а если не полный то эта:

    raise Exception("Failed to create a model")
Exception: Failed to create a model

Comment: а после когда в обсалютном путе добавляю r выскакивает опять это:

    raise Exception("Failed to create a model")
Exception: Failed to create a model

Comment: @TopikLite вероятно скачаная модель битая, попробуй скачать занова, так же есть вероятность что при копировании путей скопировался левый бит, прописывай пути в ручную, так же небольшая вероятность, что воск не дружит с кирилицей в путях, здесь только вынести модель в корень диска.